# Can BCNF only be violated when table contains more than one candidate key?

Tags: database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies, bcnf

I read in a book : "BCNF can be violated only when table contains more than one candidate key."
Consider the following example:

`Sn  Rollno      Name    Game
1   u11co098    Robert  Basketball
2   u11ce034    Bob     Cricket
3   u11co098    Robert  Cricket
4   u11me049    Hogart  Volleyball`

From above table it can be seen that
`Sn` is a primary key
FDs

`Rollno -> Name
Sn -> Rollno, Name, Game`

Now according to statement above table is in BCNF form as it has only one primary key or candidate key.
Isn't FD `Rollno -> Name` violating BCNF? (As `Rollno` is not a candidate key)

Comment: Which book? Because we should all avoid it . . .

Comment: The book probably says, **When a table is in 3NF** "BCNF can be violated only when [the] table contains more than one candidate key"--that is correct. Moreover the CKs have to overlap.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your posted relation `is not in 3NF` cause there exist a `transitive dependency` like

> Sn -> Rollno, Name, Game

so `sn -> rollno` and `Rollno -> Name`

We need to decompose the schema like below

```
R1(Sn, Rollno, Game)

R2(Rollno, Name)
```

A candidate key is a key which uniquely determines all other fields; but the one which been selected to act as primary key becomes PK.

Defn: `A table is said to be in BCNF if it don't have any overlapping candidate key`

Now both relation R1 and R2 are in BCNF.